# How to return the last element in stack

Tags: python

I am doing my lab homework for python and I am stuck on one of the questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So the task is to find whether a string has balanced brackets or not. This means that each closing bracket should be in order.

Balanced bracket example:

```
(<>){}
```

Unbalanced bracket example:

```
())

(<)>  (this one is mistmatched)

)(<>
```

The part I am stuck on is; how can I return the last element of the stack to compare?

```
def balanced_brackets(text):
    s = Stack()
    opening_bracket_list = ["(", "[", "{"]
    closing_bracket_dict = {")":"(", "]" : "[", "}" : "{"}
    text_list = list(text)

    for element in text_list:
        if element in opening_bracket_list:
           s.push(element)
        if element in closing_bracket_dict:
           if (last element of the stack) == closing_bracket_dict[element]:
              s.pop()
        else:
            return False

if s == []:
    return True
```

As you can see, I split the text into a string and use a for loop. If its an opening bracket, I push it into the stack, if its a closing element, I check if the last element of the stack matches the value from the dictionary. If no it return `False`, if yes it returns `True`.

Any other suggestions to help the code would also be greatly appreciated. I use code runner for this and I can only use a stack and specifically a function (not a class) for this lab question

Comment: If your Stack class doesn't have a method for inspecting the top element, then you can `pop()` it, compare it, then if necessary `push()` it back again

Comment: In this case where (((((((xyz)))))) is the test and there are more opening bracckets than closing bracket, how would you suggest I check if the stack is empty?

Comment: @Matthew Nobody here knows your Stack class, so we can't tell.

Comment: @Matthew Oh well, you could push a special character to the stack before you do anything else, and then at the end, pop and check whether you get that special character. But there really should be a way to ask the stack directly without such a trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, there's a `peek()` operation that gets the top element without removing it. If `peek()` isn't supported, it can be simulated by `pop`ping the top element and `push`ing it back on. You don't need to do any of that here, though, because you can just `pop` the element to compare it:

```
for element in text_list:
    if element in opening_bracket_list:
       s.push(element)
    elif element in closing_bracket_dict:
       if s.pop() != closing_bracket_dict[element]:
          return False
```

You'll also need to `return True` at the end if everything matched.

Comment: How would I test if the stack is empty at the end?

Comment: @Matthew: For types designed following standard Python container conventions, it'd be `if not s:`, since anything with a nonzero `len` is considered true and anything with a zero `len` is considered false. If your stack doesn't support `len`, see if there's an `empty` method or a `size` method you can use.